# Calling macro variables in SAS

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I'm working with SAS enterprise 7.1 and I would like to know if there's any difference between calling a macro variable with &var. vs &var, that is, without the final dot. In general, I see that both methods work, but I would like to know if there's something that I'm missing. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want to include a macro variable as part of the text how do you tell SAS that the macro variable has ended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the scenario below:

```
%let myVar = Demo;

libname example "/home/myName/&myVar85";
```

SAS will look for the macro variable &myVar85 here. But my macro variable is only myVar....so adding a period tells SAS this is the end of the macro variable and to resolve it.

```
libname example "/home/myName/&myVar.85";
```

If you were using it as part of the file path remember to add an extra `.` for the extension.

```
ods excel file="/home/myName/&myVar..xlsx" style=meadow;

proc print data=sashelp.class;
run;

ods excel close;
```

Answer (score 1):

For consistency it's best to always finish with a ".", I reckon.
Indeed, the *need* is not always there, but the use case outlined above hopefully explains why "." is sometimes needed :)